# Xubuntu 19.10: Keyboard and mouse stop working a few minutes after signin (USB issue?)

Tags: usb, keyboard, xubuntu, mouse, 19.10

I'm running Xubuntu 19.10 on a new Dell Precision 5820.  Machine worked great for a few weeks until today.  Now, a few minutes after logging in, the keyboard and mouse stop responding.  The system isn't frozen (running applications continue to do so with no problem) but I can't provide any input.  Can't move the mouse or click, can't switch to a virtual terminal, no SysReq combinations, nothing.    The CapsLock lights on the keyboard no longer toggle when the key is pressed.

Based on this and some log entries (pasted below) I am guessing the problem is with USB devices in general.

I've tried booting into an earlier kernel version, logging in as a different user, unplugging and replugging the keyboard and mouse, and plugging in a second keyboard, but none of these have helped.  Any help would be most welcome, the machine is essentially unusable at this point -- I just get a few minutes after logging in before this happens.

I've copied some entries from /var/log/syslog that may be relevant.  Similar messages appear whenever the problem occurs.

```
Apr  3 11:38:05 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2081.985153] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:38:11 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2087.220959] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr  3 11:38:16 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2092.596995] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr  3 11:38:16 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2092.805041] usb 1-4: device not accepting address 3, error -62
Apr  3 11:38:16 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2092.933109] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:38:21 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2097.973165] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr  3 11:38:27 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2103.349154] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr  3 11:38:27 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2103.557150] usb 1-4: device not accepting address 3, error -62
Apr  3 11:38:27 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2103.685160] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:38:32 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2108.853249] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  3 11:38:48 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2124.469303] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  3 11:38:48 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2124.705353] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:38:53 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2129.845386] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  3 11:39:09 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2145.461490] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  3 11:39:09 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2145.569571] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
Apr  3 11:39:09 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2145.797464] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 11:39:14 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2150.965415] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
Apr  3 11:39:14 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2150.965422] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Apr  3 11:39:14 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2150.965468] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
Apr  3 11:39:14 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2150.965490] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
Apr  3 11:39:14 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2150.965507] usb 2-9: USB disconnect, device number 2
Apr  3 11:39:14 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.041981] usb 2-10: USB disconnect, device number 3
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.385436] usb 1-4: device not accepting address 9, error -108
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.385496] usb usb1-port4: couldn't allocate usb_device
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.385519] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.385777] usblp0: removed
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.386106] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 4
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 13
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 15
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.565979] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 5
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.630059] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.630431] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 7
Apr  3 11:39:15 RACHMANINOFF3 kernel: [ 2151.630435] usb 1-10.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
```